# PHP: Is there any kind of sanitization I need for using _GET data?

Tags: php, sanitization

For just regular use in my PHP code, that is.  Not like I'm going to pass it to my queries or anything.

Comment: Define "regular use"? Can you show some examples?

Comment: Sanitization eases the mind and can mitigate unexpected edge cases in the processing logic. But only escaping at the right places brings security. Also every variable needs specific [filtering](http://sourceforge.net/p/php7framework/wiki/input/), but you cannot possibly sanitize everything.

Comment: Well I think the closest thing to a danger would be checking if files exist by the given name within a directory list...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- If you pass them to SQL queries, you get an SQL injection
- If you use them to form file names, you get an arbitrary file reading vulnerability
- If you output them as-is to the user as a part of HTML page, you get an XSS vulnerability
- If you output them to a file, you may get a malformed file if it has some predetermined formatting
- If you're just comparing the value with a set of predefined values, you're fine.
- If you're converting it to a number, you're fine as long as any number works for you

Answer (score 2):

This can really be answered only by stepping through your code, and looking exactly what it does. There could be pitfalls in your code (like a badly built `switch` statement) that could require sanitation.

Other than database queries, general scenarios where you *need* to sanitize incoming data include:

- Using it in a file name
- Using it to include a file
- Using it to pass parameters to a program executed through `exec()`
- Outputting it to HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need whatever your application and its security require, keeping in mind that you can get absolutely anything (or nothing) in a `$_GET` parameter.  Maybe you are not using the value in queries, but you may be subject to a cross-site scripting attack if you blindly use a value in a page, for example.  "Harmless" websites can easily fall into a cross-site scripting attack.

Never trust user input, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize variables depending on the content of them and the use of them.

so if you have a variable like so:

- `$_GET['page_id']`

And your using within the database, then your sanitize it.

if you have a variable like so:

- `$_GET['action']`

And your planning on using like

- `require_once "pages/" . $_GET['action'] . ".php"`

then you sanitize before you do that, otherwise just make sure that `register_globals` is off and you will be ok aslong as your not using them in places without considerable thought

Answer (score 0):

Everything that's is not coming from your server should be sanitized! This includes `$_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER` just to name a few.